# Why does not java 8 implement basic collection functions in Collection?

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

With java 8, now we can use the `java.util.Collection.stream` to do some collection basic functions such as `filter`, `map`, `collect`, `anyMatch`, etc.

The problem is when you have a Collection and you have to use some of this functions, the code gets a little ugly, for example:

```
List<String> ids = this.getFriends(userId).stream().map(Friend::getFriendUserId).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

In this case, I have a `List<Friend>` and I want to have a `List<String>` that gets populated with the friendId of every item in the first List.

What I think is that maybe the code could be like this:

```
List<String> ids = this.getFriends(userId).map(Friend::getFriendUserId);
```

This of course is more readable and also more clean, but invalid as `List` does not understand the message map. I can't understand what would be the problem of implementing this in Java 8, and why do they decide to force every time to convert to `Stream` when in some cases we then convert it back to a `Collection` as in this case.

Comment: The main reason is it's dangerous to add (default) methods on a popular interface, since it may break some subtypes in the wild. It is very likely that someone has a subtype of List with its own `map` method; it won't compile under java 8 if `List.map` is added in java 8.

Comment: That's why they were very conservative in adding methods to Collections APIs. And still there have been complaints about breakage.

Comment: @bayou.io well, that's a good  and I think you should write it as one.

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of `.stream()` is very simple. Just update your API to return the streams, not collections. Also name your methods returning streams using just plural nouns. So it's better to replace

```
public List<Friend> getFriends(String userId) { ... }
```

With

```
public Stream<Friend> friends(String userId) { ... }
```

This scenario is widely used in JDK. Examples: `BufferedReader.lines()`, `Random.ints()`, `ZipFile.entries()`, `String.chars()` and so on (more to come in JDK-9).

The second thing you may do is to import statically `Collectors`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

This will shorten `Collectors.toList()` to simple `toList()`:

```
List<String> ids = this.friends(userId).map(Friend::getFriendUserId).collect(toList());
```

Which is already much shorter.

Finally you should think whether it's actually necessary to collect the resulting stream into `List`. Sometimes it's reasonable, but often it's just pre-Java-8 thinking like you need everything in collections. For example, if you want to use this list to iterate over it, why not iterating the stream itself using `Stream.forEach()`?

Comment: I disagree with the sentiment; `List` is still a very useful concept; we cannot second guess programmer's choice of using List. Even if `Stream` is better in a use case, from some ivory tower point of view, we cannot blame a programmer for using `List` if it models the problem better, from his point of view. After all, a computer language is there to serve the programmer.

Comment: You have your point there, but I agree with @bayou.io 's comment because I wont change all my model..